# URL Rewrite - replace dots with hyphens

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

**Context**

I have some urls in my app and some of them used to contain version numbers, ie.

`http://myapp.com/some/path/1.2.3`
or
`http://myapp.com/some/1.2.3`

**Problem**

The application is being rewriten to have `-` instead of those `.` in the URLs. For some reason it's impossible to allow `.` anymore. I would like to create a Rewrite rule that will accept requests in old format and rewrite them to a new one. A version will always have 2 dots.

**Stack**

PHP.exe running on IIS

**EDIT**
2 dots!

Comment: Ideal solution would be an equivalent to a simple string.replace(".","-")

Comment: Does `IIS` support .htaccess?

Comment: I can convert .htaccess to it's ruleset.

Comment: URLs don't have to show dots, I want the client's with old URLs to still work thorugh the rewrite module.

Comment: I can provide a .htaccess rule to redirect but I can only test it on Apache

Comment: Please do, I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A version will always have 3 dots.

I guess you meant 2 dots and 3 numbers.

This rule will redirect `/1.2.3` to `/1_2_3`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*/\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/?$ /$1-$2-$3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Also I used `-` instead of `_` to connect the sections.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I meant `-` but typed `_` (corrected now)